# How save global visible user in angular 2 application?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

After login I get user

```
  private login() {
    let data = { "UserName": "admin" , "Password": "+" };

    this.apiService.doLogin(data).subscribe(
      (res) => this.userService.set('user', res),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    )
  }
```

How I can implement this userService?
* I want get some user data without new call to back end? 
** I know about https://github.com/ngrx/store, maybe someone know better solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. If you want to store it in memory, you can just use `this.userService.user = res.json()`. If you want to persist it (i.e. find it back if you refresh the page), you can store it in a cookie or in LocalStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to storage your logged user details, you can do this in few ways.

**Redux store (ngrx):**

You could use ngrx store concept - https://github.com/ngrx/store. When you get your user model from backend, you just have to *dispatch* an action to load data.

**Advantages:**

- You could *subscribe* your user store in all pieces of application, in each component, so you can properly react on every change,
- User model in store would be *immutable* - to change anything, you have to dispatch an action, which invokes pure reducer function, so it is not possible to modify any user data by accident.

**Service:**

Also, you could store your user model object in service as a private *variable*.

**Disadvantages:**

- In Angular 2, services could be global or module scoped. What does it mean? That if you add your user service into *global* module providers array and by mistake - also as your *feature* module provider, angular 2 will create **two** instances of your service, so one of them - will have empty user. Similar problem you can find there - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#q-why-it-is-bad

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5localSorage**  can be used but for **Angular2, ngrx/store** is better. It also provides **state management** so its recommended to use it.